# Why can't I switch branches, when trying to use "git checkout" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've been working on a website using Visual Studio Code. I've branched off of main this weekend on a desktop. I pushed all of the changes to the remote.

Later on my laptop, where I thought I had the main branch cloned, when I tried running the command `git checkout`, but it didn't find anything branches. I'm still new to using Git so I'm sure I've done something wrong, but don't know what. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the things you should consider before using `git checkout`:

- Check if you changed something, you can do that by the command: `git status`
- If you did changed something, you can either `commit` or `stash` the changes.

  - `stash` removes all your changes made.
  - `commit` adds all your changes *(affects only your branch)*.
- If you choose to remove the changes, you can simply use the command: `git stash`
- If you choose to add the changes. Do the following command:

  - `git add .` adds all your changes.
  - `git commit -m 'Hey I changed something'` commits the changes to your `local branch

After that, you can now use `git checkout`. Note, by the time you checkout, all the changes you committed under your branch will be pushed to where you checked out.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, your laptop code repo does not have the latest code. You branched off [created `newBranch`] from main and did your changes and pushed to remote on your desktop, but your laptop does not know this has happenned.

In order for the laptop repo be aware of the changes, you need to tell git to fetch the latest changes. You can do so using
 `git fetch`
Once you execute this command, your laptop's local git will be aware that there is a new branch available. And once you do

```
git checkout newBranch
git pull
```

you will be able to access the code on your lapi that you pushed from your desktop earlier.

Comment: `fetch` or `pull` will tell local git any remote branch update.